# android emulator is start but window show blank screen

Tags: android-emulator

when i run the andrioid application. emulator is start well, but screen doesn't show anything.

Comment: Well, *is it supposed* to show anything? If yes, what? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: thanks i tried to debug the application. but emulator is present on starting stage. it takes more time. please help me. i cant run any application.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old thread, but it seems that when the name of the AVD contains numerals, the AVD will not "boot" at all. The window shows up, but it never even gets to the "A N D R O I D _" screen.

As soon as I recreated an AVD with the name containing only alphabet characters, it would start properly.

Answer (score 0):

That seams a problem of 1.6

Upgrade to 2.1 and shall disappear.